# Add/Delete optional personal form in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

What is simplest/best way to achieve functionality in vba in Excel:
- button "add person" which will add 4 rows in which user specifies name...,
also "
- button "delete person" appearing in new added entry - to delete it

What is a workflow for doing that?

Should I record that first?
Should I write VBA only? How to keep the part that can be added/deleted - somewhere hidden or in VBA?

Comment: What have your tried so far?  Does the button need to insert the rows at a particular point in the worksheet, or does it just have to populate cells at the end of a range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well the simplest solution is to create macros;

1. to add person
   after that, you need to assign this macro to the button with vba ( by right click and assign macro).and loop it 4 times.
2. to delete person -->1st you make the button and set the visibility to false. After that you need to identify the row number, and set the button to visible in vba